# Webscraping between two tags

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the following page(s):

Htpps://mywebsite.com

In particular, I would like to get the name of each entry. I noticed that the text I am interested in is always in (MY TEXT) the middle of these two tags:  `<div class="title"> <a href="your text"> MY TEXT </a>`

I know how to search for these tags individually:

```
#load libraries 
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(XML)
library(rvest)

# set up page
url<-"https://www.mywebsite.com"
page <-read_html(url)

#option 1
b = page %>% html_nodes("title")

option1 <- b %>% html_text() %>% strsplit("\\n")

#option 2
b = page %>% html_nodes("a")

option2 <- b %>% html_text() %>% strsplit("\\n")
```

**Is there some way that I could have specified the "html_nodes" argument so that it picked up on "MY TEXT" - i.e. scrape between  `<div class="title">` and `</a>` :**

```
 <div class="title"> <a href="your text"> MY TEXT </a>
```

Comment: Use `html_text2()` instead

Comment: @ Tom Hoel: Thank you so much for this comment! I have never heard of the  "html_text2()" function before.  What are the benefits of this function? How would I use it in my case? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scraping of pages `1:10`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

my_function <- function(page_n) {
  
  cat("Scraping page ", page_n, "\n")
  
  page <- paste0("https://www.dentistsearch.ca/search-doctor/",
    page_n, "?category=0&services=0&province=55&city=&k=") %>% read_html
  
  tibble(title = page %>%
           html_elements(".title a") %>%
           html_text2(),
         adress = page %>%  
           html_elements(".marker") %>% 
           html_text2(),
         page = page_n)
}

df <- map_dfr(1:10, my_function)
```

Comment: @ Tom Hoel: Thank you so much for your answer! I tried to modify your code for a related question - can you please take a look at it if you have time? thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob the information you are looking for is produced by javascript, which `rvest` is unable to read. I have no good suggestions for that problem, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the xpath argument inside `html_elements` to locate each `a` tag inside a `div` with class "title".

Here's a complete reproducible example.

```r
library(rvest)

"https://www.mywebsite.ca/extension1/" %>%
  paste0("2?extension2") %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_elements(xpath = "//div[@class='title']/a") %>% 
  html_text()
```

Or to get all entries on the first 10 pages:

```r
library(rvest)

unlist(lapply(1:10, function(page){
"https://www.mywebsite.ca/extension1/" %>%
  paste0(page, "?extension2") %>%
  read_html() %>%
  html_elements(xpath = "//div[@class='title']/a") %>% 
  html_text()}))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @ Allan Cameron: thank you so much for your answer! This code xpath = "//div[@class='title']/a" allows me to search between two tags? div[@class='title'] and "a"? thank you!

Comment: @stats_noob it specifically finds div tags with class "title" and looks inside them for "a" tags, just as you wanted.